# Why do I get: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I am getting invalid syntax on the following:

```
rootdir = 'c://temp/test//files//'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fileParts = file.split('.')
        if len(fileParts) > 1:
            stripper = fileParts([len(fileParts)-2]
            print(stripper)
```

Comment: Next time, can you include the full error message. This was more okay because the snippet is pretty short.

Comment: use Eclipse! http://pydev.org/ ... I did try others too (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors) but for me Eclipse was a clear winner ...

Comment: thanks StefanNch, just starting out, good tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stripper = fileParts([len(fileParts)-2]
                                       ^
```

there's a missing closing parenthesis `)`, should be:

```
stripper = fileParts([len(fileParts)-2])
                                       ^
```

*Aside*: You might find some of the functions in the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module useful, in particular [os.path.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.split) and [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext). Should you need to put paths together later, [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.join) is good to use.

Comment: @edelwater ha ha .. been there myself :) .. sometimes it helps having another set of eyes take a look.

Comment: was busy coding clicked the wrong V grin sorry i better get to bed

Answer (score 1):

The error was in line 6 of code, correct version below:

```
stripper = fileParts([len(fileParts)-2]
```

You need a syntax check editor or IDE.